# Need advice about AES CTR cipher python vs. Java

Tags: java, aes, pycrypto, python-simple-crypt

I'm working on project when some arbitrary data are encrypted using Python [simple-crypt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simple-crypt) (source [here](https://github.com/andrewcooke/simple-crypt)) and same encrypted data are then used in java application.

I would like to understand conceptual difference between JSSE and Pycrypto.

This is python part doing encryption ([source](https://github.com/andrewcooke/simple-crypt/blob/master/src/simplecrypt/__init__.py#L44)):

```
counter = Counter.new(HALF_BLOCK, prefix=salt[:HALF_BLOCK//8])
cipher = AES.new(cipher_key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=counter)
```

This is my attempt for java re-implementation of same operation:

```
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(cipher_key, "AES");
IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(salt, 0, HALF_BLOCK / 8);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding", "BC");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
```

Problem here is that initialization of java Cipher throw exception:

```
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: IV must be 16 bytes long.
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCEBlockCipher.engineInit(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1394)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1327)
```

Value of HALF_BLOCK is 64.

So question is, how does python's AES implementation works with HALF_BLOCK/8 key size and java's not?

Thanks!

Comment: It is generally best not to use CTR mode, is is very easy to get it wrong. The issue is that the same key and counter must **never** be reused. Generally CBC mode is used with a random IV and PKCS#7 padding is used to accommodate input that is not a multiple of the block size.

Comment: @zaph : that's true.Unfortunately it's requirement given by used python library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nonce (the "left side" of the IV; the "right" being the sequential counter) should be transported alongside the cipher text as the IV. There is no need to keep the nonce secret. It just **must not** be re-used for another message encrypted by the same key.

It appears the Python code is generating a new `Counter` which is `64` bits long and sets the `prefix` (I'm assuming the `nonce` value) to be the first `8` bytes of the `salt` variable. It likely (huge assumption here because I don't have access to the Python code) starts the actual **counter** value at `0x00` * 8, so your initial IV would be:

```
salt = '#Eg����' # => UTF-8 encoding of 0x0123456789ABCDEF (not familiar enough with Python for the actual expression)
# Really may be misunderstanding, but as the AES IV must be 16 bytes, I imagine the terminology here is prefix = 8 bytes, sequence = 8 bytes
counter = Counter.new(HALF_BLOCK, prefix=salt[:HALF_BLOCK]) # => '0x01234567 89ABCDEF 00000000 00000000'
# Perform one encryption
counter # => '0x01234567 89ABCDEF 00000000 00000001'
# etc.
```

To perform the same operation in Java, it should be as simple as initializing your `IvParameterSpec` to the same as above (i.e. right-pad the first 8 bytes of the salt with `0` to 16 bytes).

```
// Intentionally verbose for demonstration; this can obviously be compacted
byte[] salt = org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex.decode("0123456789ABCDEF");
byte[] nonceAndCounter = new byte[16];
System.arraycopy(salt, 0, nonceAndCounter, 0, ((int) (HALF_BLOCK / 8)));
IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(nonceAndCounter);
```

Here's a full test case which asserts that the encrypt and decrypt are internally compatible; you could also run this with data from the Python side to verify.

```
    @Test
    public void testPythonCompatibility() {
        // Arrange
        byte[] cipher_key = org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex.decode("0123456789ABCDEFFEDCBA9876543210");
        final int HALF_BLOCK = 64;
        byte[] salt = org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex.decode("0123456789ABCDEF");
        byte[] nonceAndCounter = new byte[16];
        System.arraycopy(salt, 0, nonceAndCounter, 0, ((int) (HALF_BLOCK / 8)));
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(nonceAndCounter);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding", "BC");
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(cipher_key, "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

        final String plaintext = "This is a plaintext message.";

        // Act
        byte[] cipherBytes = cipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        // Assert
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
        byte[] recoveredBytes = cipher.doFinal(cipherBytes);
        String recovered = new String(recoveredBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        assert recovered.equals(plaintext);
    }
```

Comment: Note: The default initial_value of PyCrypto's `Counter.new` is 1, you need to set it according to the value used in java.

Comment: What is `"BC"` in `Cipher.getInstance`

Comment: That indicates it is using [The Legion Of The Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) as the security provider. You could also use the native Sun JCE, etc. See the [JCA](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#Provider) documentation for more info.